# What is this game shown on the TV series Preacher?

Tags: game-identification

In the TV series *Preacher*, Odin Quinncannon plays the computer game shown in the screenshot below. The characters on the left and right look very familiar to me. Does anybody know this game?

[image]

Comment: Fun fact: Q*bert was featured prominently in the film Wreck-It Ralph.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While I was hoping to find this might be Faster Harder More Challenging Q*bert (see: [Wikipedia's article on Q*bert: Section on Faster Harder More Challenging Q*bert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert#Faster_Harder_More_Challenging_Q.2Abert)), my research indicates that this is from Q*bert Rebooted's classic mode (see: [Wikipedia's article on Q*bert: Section on Q*bert Rebooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert#Q.2Abert_Rebooted)), based on the side artwork and some image searching.  (e.g., seen in media shown at [Steam's page for Q*bert Rebooted](http://store.steampowered.com/app/285960/), or if you scroll down a bit on this page: [Playstation Lifestyle: Q*bert PS4](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2015/02/23/qbert-ps4-review-classic-revisited/#/slide/1).)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The image posted by the O.P. is of Q*bert Rebooted. The accepted answer is referencing the original Q*bert.

Answer (score 35):

[This is Qbert.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert)

[image]

> Q*bert is an arcade video game developed and published by Gottlieb in 1982. It is a 2D action game with puzzle elements that uses "isometric" graphics to create a pseudo-3D effect, and serves as a precursor to the isometric platformer genre. The objective is to change the color of every cube in a pyramid by making the on-screen character hop on top of the cube while avoiding obstacles and enemies. Players use a joystick to control the character.